# Npm install issue on Virtualbox with Ubuntu installed

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, webpack, virtualbox

Just wonder if anyone could shed some light on `npm install` running on Virtualbox machine (with Ubuntu v16.4 installed).. I'm getting this sorry of error

```
osboxes@osboxes:/media/sf_ubuntu/angular$ npm install
app@0.0.0 /media/sf_ubuntu/angular
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.2.3
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.2.3

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@~2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN app@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path ../acorn/bin/acorn
npm ERR! code EROFS
npm ERR! errno -30
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! rofs EROFS: read-only file system, symlink '../acorn/bin/acorn' -> '/media/sf_ubuntu/angular/node_modules/.bin/acorn'
npm ERR! rofs This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! rofs and is related to the file system being read-only.
npm ERR! rofs 
npm ERR! rofs Often virtualized file systems, or other file systems
npm ERR! rofs that don't support symlinks, give this error.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /media/sf_ubuntu/angular/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Comment: Is 'read-only' selected for your shared Virtualbox folder?

Comment: what is /media/sf_ubuntu/angular ? Is it a network path or a removable drive? If so you need to check its permissions.

Comment: It appears to be a permission issue. I had to move the package.json to a folder inside ubuntu HDD. It run okay now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtualbox limits the creating of symlink in shared directory in terms of safety. So you should open relevant feature:

1. Close Virtualbox
2. Add the installation path of Virtualbox to environment variable PATH
3. Execute the command below in cmd

   `VBoxManage setextradata <VM_NAME> VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/<SHARE_NAME(without the sf_ prefix)> 1`
4. Run Virtualbox with admin

Comment: Somehow the code showing above is incomplete. Complete code here. VBoxManage setextradata <VM_NAME> VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/<SHARE_NAME(without the 'sf_' prefix)> 1